# How to show default values on a complex module in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

My code is done in this way to enforce a choice in the first input cant show in the second one

```
# Define the UI for the module letter
letterUI <- function(id, input_id, default_value = NULL) {
  selectizeInput(NS(id, input_id), label = "Ratings", choices = NULL, 
                 multiple = TRUE, selected = default_value)
}

letterServer <- function(id, modalities, default_values) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {

    observe({
      updateSelectizeInput(session, "letters_1", choices = modalities, 
                           selected = default_values$letters_1)
      updateSelectizeInput(session, "letters_2", choices = modalities, 
                           selected = default_values$letters_2)
      updateSelectizeInput(session, "letters_3", choices = modalities, 
                           selected = default_values$letters_3)
    })
    
    observeEvent({
      input$letters_2
      input$letters_3
    }, {
      updateSelectizeInput(session, "letters_1", choices = modalities[!modalities %in% c(input$letters_2, input$letters_3)], 
                           selected = input$letters_1)
    }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
    
    observeEvent({
      input$letters_1
      input$letters_3
    }, {
      updateSelectizeInput(session, "letters_2", choices = modalities[!modalities %in% c(input$letters_1, input$letters_3)], 
                           selected = input$letters_2)
    }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
    
    observeEvent({
      input$letters_2
      input$letters_1
    }, {
      updateSelectizeInput(session, "letters_3", choices = modalities[!modalities %in% c(input$letters_2, input$letters_1)], 
                           selected = input$letters_3)
    }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)

    onRestore(function(state) {
      observeEvent(reactiveVal(TRUE), {
        updateSelectizeInput(session, "letters_1", selected = state$input$letters_1)
        updateSelectizeInput(session, "letters_2", selected = state$input$letters_2)
        updateSelectizeInput(session, "letters_3", selected = state$input$letters_3)
      })
    })

    letters_1 <- reactive(input$letters_1)
    letters_2 <- reactive(input$letters_2)
    letters_3 <- reactive(input$letters_3)

    return_list <- list(
      letters_1 = letters_1,
      letters_2 = letters_2,
      letters_3 = letters_3
    )

    return(return_list)
  })
}

# Define the UI for the Shiny app
ui <- fluidPage(
  letterUI("letters", "letters_1", default_value = "A"),
  letterUI("letters", "letters_2", default_value = c("B", "C")),
  letterUI("letters", "letters_3", default_value = 'D')
)

# Define the server logic for the Shiny app
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  modalities <- LETTERS[1:10]
  letters_chosen <- letterServer('letters',modalities = modalities,default_values = list(letters_1 = 'A',
  letters_2 = 'B',letters_3 = 'C'))
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

The fix is to use update at the start of the app

```
# Define the UI for the module letter
letterUI <- function(id, input_id) {
  selectizeInput(NS(id, input_id), label = "Ratings", choices = NULL, multiple = TRUE)
}


letterServer <- function(id, default_values) {

  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {


    modalities <- LETTERS[1:10]

    observe({
      updateSelectizeInput(session, "letters_1", choices = modalities,selected = LETTERS[1:3])
      updateSelectizeInput(session, "letters_2", choices = modalities,selected = LETTERS[4:6])
      updateSelectizeInput(session, "letters_3", choices = modalities,selected = LETTERS[7:10])
    })
    
    observeEvent({
      input$letters_2
      input$letters_3
    }, {
      updateSelectizeInput(session, "letters_1", choices = modalities[!modalities %in% c(input$letters_2, input$letters_3)], selected = input$letters_1)
    }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
    observeEvent({
      input$letters_1
      input$letters_3
    }, {
      updateSelectizeInput(session, "letters_2", choices = modalities[!modalities %in% c(input$letters_1, input$letters_3)], selected = input$letters_2)
    }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
    observeEvent({
      input$letters_2
      input$letters_1
    }, {
      updateSelectizeInput(session, "letters_3", choices = modalities[!modalities %in% c(input$letters_2, input$letters_1)], selected = input$letters_3)
    }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)


    onRestore(function(state) {
      observeEvent(reactiveVal(TRUE),{
        updateSelectizeInput(session, "letters_1", selected = state$input$letters_1)
        updateSelectizeInput(session, "letters_2", selected = state$input$letters_2)
        updateSelectizeInput(session, "letters_3", selected = state$input$letters_3)

      })
      
    })


    letters_1 <- reactive(input$letters_1)
    letters_2 <- reactive(input$letters_2)
    letters_3 <- reactive(input$letters_3)

    return_list <- list(
      letters_1 = letters_1,
      letters_2 = letters_2,
      letters_3 = letters_3
    )


    return(return_list)
  })
}
```